# Python 2 install Python 3 module

Tags: python, installation

I'm trying to install latest [guess_language](https://bitbucket.org/spirit/guess_language) module. The description says it can be install using [lib3to2](https://bitbucket.org/amentajo/lib3to2). But how can i do that ?
First i install 3to2. Then

> 3to2 guess_language-spirit-0.5a1 -w

breaks package. after i run

> python setup.py install

I get message:

> Finished processing dependencies for **UNKNOWN==0.0.0**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `setup.py` runs the `lib3to2` converter for you on install, there is no need to run the converter manually.

The following (using my `pip` command installed for python 2.7) works fine for me; using `pip` is the easiest option:

```
pip install https://bitbucket.org/spirit/guess_language/downloads/guess_language-spirit-0.5a1.tar.bz2
```

provided that you have the enchant C libraries installed.

Alternatively, the following works as well, provided you have the `3to2` python package installed:

```
$ cd guess_language-spirit-0.5a1
guess_language-spirit-0.5a1 $ ../bin/python setup.py install
RefactoringTool: Skipping implicit fixer: collections
RefactoringTool: Skipping implicit fixer: int
RefactoringTool: Skipping implicit fixer: memoryview
RefactoringTool: Skipping implicit fixer: printfunction
RefactoringTool: Skipping implicit fixer: unittest
RefactoringTool: Refactored build/py2k/generate_data.py
RefactoringTool: Refactored build/py2k/guess_language/__main__.py
[..many more lines..]
Processing dependencies for guess-language-spirit==0.5a1
Finished processing dependencies for guess-language-spirit==0.5a1
```

but make sure you do that with a cleanly unpacked distribution (one you didn't try to run the 3to2 converter on).

Comment: Successfully installed UNKNOWN